# Putty does not paste from Elementary OS (Ubuntu)

Tags: ssh, elementary-os, putty

I used to use Windows but switched to Linux, I am used to use putty on Windows and to copy from Windows and paste on Putty I could just right click, but I think I might be missing some configuration, when I right click it does not paste, when I CTRL+V it does not paste, I can copy and paste any text anywhere on Elementary OS, but it just won't paste inside putty, is there some clipboard configuration on putty or something for this?...

Answer (score 0):

Try SHIFT + CTRL + V for paste

Comment: tried, but does not work, middle mouse button also does not....

Answer (score 0):

Pasting text depends on what terminal emulator you are using. On many terminal emulators, the default for pasting text from the clipboard is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Pasting can also be accomplished with the middle mouse button (usually by clicking the mouse wheel down), but this usually pastes text from the primary buffer. The primary buffer holds the text you last highlighted, which is not necessarily what is currently in your clipboard.

The right click pasting feature in PuTTY is called "Compromise". I'm not aware if it's an available configuration for any terminal emulators other than PuTTY.